# xml to php for rss feed

Tags: php, xml, rss

I am using PHP and simpleXML to read the following rss feed:

```
https://information-syndication.api.bbc.com/articles?api_key=[api_key _here]&index=indonesia-dunia&mixin=summary&mixin=hero_images&mixin=thumbnail_images
```

result :

```
 <isapi>
   <results>
    <article>
        <headline>headline</headline>
        <link>link</link>
        <summary>sumary</summary>
        <pubDate>date</pubDate>
        <thumbnail height="360" width="640" url="http://a.files.bbci.co.uk/worldservice/live/assets/images/2016/08/23/160823220838_north_korea_missile_640x360_afp_nocredit.jpg" copyrightHolder="AFP" caption="" alt="Rudal balistik Korea Utara"/>
    </article>
  </results>
 </isapi>
```

I can get most of the information I want like so:

```
<?php
   $sxml = simplexml_load_file("https://information-syndication.api.bbc.com/articles?api_key=[api_key_here]0&index=indonesia-dunia&mixin=summary&mixin=hero_images&mixin=thumbnail_images");


   foreach($sxml->results->article as $name => $results)
   {
       echo $results->headline."<br>";
       ?> 
          <a href="<?php echo $results->link; ?>"><?php echo $results->headline ?></a><br>

       <?php 
          echo $results->summary."<br>";
          echo $results->pubDate."<br>";
   }
   ?>
```

How to display images in the

```
<thumbnail height="360" width="640" url="http://a.files.bbci.co.uk/worldservice/live/assets/images/2016/08/23/160823220838_north_korea_missile_640x360_afp_nocredit.jpg" copyrightHolder="AFP" caption="" alt="Rudal balistik Korea Utara"/>
```

Comment: Shouldn't image tag be `<img>`?

Comment: you mean  ?
`<img src="<?php echo $results->thumnail ?>">`
no

Comment: The `url` part should go into the `src`

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the attribute of tag in this case you want to get url="*" attribute value, to get it iterate over the xml data and to access an attributes of an tag write 
**attributes()->nameofYourAttribute**

```
$xmlElement->thumbnail->attributes()->url;
```